# re-throwing an exception from inside a termination handler

Tags: c++, c++11

Is the following code according to the standard ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto terminationHandler = []()
    {
        try
        {
            rethrow_exception( current_exception() );
        }
        catch( exception const &exc )
        {
            cout << exc.what() << endl;
        }
        catch( ... )
        {
        }
    };
    set_terminate( terminationHandler );
    try
    {
        throw bad_alloc();
    }
    catch( ... )
    {
        terminate();
    }
}
```

This would be a nice aid for fatal situations that you still have some error-message.

I've got a function called exc_terminate() that's called like this:

```
exc_terminate( [&]() { ... do anything in local context ... } );
```

The lambda is executed within a try-catch-block and if an exception occurs the code terminates. I use this f.e. when a thread can't communicate with another thread because the synchronization-functions signalled a system_error.

Comment: A lambda that accepts no arguments and empty capture specification can be passed to `set_terminate()`.  A lambda with a non-empty capture specification or one that is called with arguments cannot.   Generally, however, `std::terminate()` and any registered terminate handlers will not be called if a thrown exception is caught - so your catching and calling `terminate()` is pointless.    The technique of throwing/catching an active exception (in order to, say, do something based on the type of the exception) is usually used in exception handlers, not terminate handlers.

Comment: You'really irritating because you don't understand my question. It's just demonstration code to ask, if current_exception() can be caugt safely from a termination-hadler. Imagine practical code yourself. I didn't ask if a termination handler is called if an exception occurs.

Comment: Your question didn't make clear whether your aim was to throw/catch exceptions in the exception handler, the terminate handler, or something else, so I covered the bases.    If you bothered to read my previous comment, I mentioned that throwing/catching in a terminate handler is discouraged.   You might want to work on asking clearer or more focused questions, rather than ones which require readers to guess, or cover multiple bases.

Comment: The purpose is self-explanatory from the source. A termination handler should not throw an exception out of itself, but why should throwing within a termination handler not throw an exception it catches itself ?

Comment: A terminate handler (like `std::terminate()`) is called when the process of handling an exception (e.g. stack unwinding) has to be abandoned.    There is no guarantee that an implementation can properly handle a new exception when it is in the process of abandoning the process of exception handling.

Comment: It's very unlikely that you can't use the standard library in a termination handler. The standard library can throw bad_alloc() and some other exceptions at a lot of places. This would be consdidered as an incomplete impelmentation. no matter if this is up to the standard or not (you don't know it).

Comment: "**[terminate.handler]/2** *Required behavior:* A `terminate_handler` shall terminate execution of the program without returning to the caller." Your `terminationHandler ` exhibits undefined behavior for this reason, if nothing else.

Comment: The above is a code-example for the question if a current_exception can be re-thrown inside a termination-handler, nothing more. For this question it doesn't need to be complete.

Comment: I believe it's OK for terminate handler to use exceptions internally. I don't see anything in the standard to prohibit it. The standard suggests the terminate handler is treated similarly to a "normal" exception handler: "**[except.handle]/7** A handler is considered active when initialization is complete for the formal parameter (if any) of the catch
clause... Also, an implicit handler is considered active when `std::terminate()` or `std::unexpected()` is entered due to a throw." This is what allows `current_exception()` to work in the first place.

Comment: Meanwhile I also think that, but I think peter has still his special opionions. ;-)